# NSPredicate one-to-many dates comparing

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I'm trying to get all objects, where one of tasks was completed in past.

My predicate:

```
//Other Class
NSString *predicateFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"status.objectId != '142' && status.objectId != '143' && deleted == 0 && ANY tasks.complete_till < %@",[NSDate date]];

class.predicateFormat = predicateFormat;

//Other class
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:_predicateFormat];
```

complete_till - date in database

Any other predicates with ANY works fine, but dates causes crash:

```
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format
> string "status.objectId != '142' && status.objectId != '143' &&
> deleted == 0 && ANY tasks.complete_till < 2014-08-28 20:51:18 +0000"'
```

Update:

```
ANY tasks.complete_till < 2014-08-29 05:15:27 +0000
```

Causes crash too.

Comment: hello @itruf, is `tasks.complete_till` of type `NSDate` object? because you are simply comparing it as string which will not work. both should be of same type either NSString or NSDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found, that nsstring stringWithFormat: returns different, than predicateWithFormat.

It was my problem

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell where the issue is without seeing the actual object you are applying this to.

I assume you object has a status on it that has an objectId i.e. fooBar.status.objectId

Start breaking down your predicate. First start with

[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status.objectId != '142'"];

Then add

[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status.objectId != '142' && status.objectId != '143'];

Comment: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY tasks.complete_till < 2014-08-29 05:15:27 +0000"] crashes app too

Comment: This tells me its your date comparison. Does the app work correctly when you don't have the date compare?